# Can MSBuild's SignFile be used without installing the certificate?

Tags: msbuild, certificate, clickonce, assembly-signing

I have a ClickOnce app that I am updated to be deployed using a modern deployment Jenkins Pipeline with MSBuild.  Part of this effort is signing the .manifest and .application files.

Previously we used `<SignFile>` with MSBuild to sign these, using certificates that were installed in the user's personal store on the build machine. It worked with:

```
<SignFile SigningTarget="MyApp.exe.manifest" 
          CertificateThumbprint="1a 9f ..." 
          TimestampUrl="http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll" />
<SignFile SigningTarget="MyApp.application" 
          CertificateThumbprint="1a 9f ..." 
          TimestampUrl="http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll" />
```

However, in the 21st century we prefer to have everything we need to build either in version control or available in a secret store via an API, so that we no longer depend on the build server to be in a certain state.

**So how can we use SignFile to sign a ClickOnce manifest and application without the certificate needing to be installed?**  Or am I not thinking about this right?

If there is a better way than using `<SignFile>`, let me know--as far as I can tell, SignTool.exe and Mage.exe both require the certificate to be installed as well.

Comment: Possibly relevant [Rube Goldberg approach here](https://www.karpach.com/visual-studio-team-services-assembly-signing.htm), but I believe there's probably a better way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the old mage.exe is more full-featured than SignTool.

So I copied mage.exe to my project dependencies folder from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools`, then in MSBuild,  this worked for me:

```
<Message Text="Signing APP manifest (.exe.manifest)" />
<Exec Command="Dependencies\mage.exe -sign $(MyAppManifest).exe.manifest -CertFile MyLocalKey.pfx -Password MyPassword123" />
```

Then I did something very similar to that for the deployment manifest (.application) file.

Apparently the newer versions of mage.exe can indeed support SHA-256, contrary to some web pages I found on the topic (perhaps they were older).